# mongodb shard replication member: could not find member to sync from

Tags: mongodb, deployment, replication, sharding, replicaset

I am trying to set up mongodb that have shards with replica set and I enabled --rest so I can view my shards on my browser however, when I view  "replSetGetStatus" it shows "could not find member to sync from" [image of my replica members on my browser](http://i290.photobucket.com/albums/ll275/Laosts/repset_zps8sbzc836.png)

 
My list of Replica Members when I do rs.status() on my Primary replication

```
{
    "set" : "S1repset",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-09-29T16:19:22.020Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "name" : "10.10.30.10:10000",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 1,
                    "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                    "uptime" : 18374,
                    "optime" : Timestamp(1443538866, 970),
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-09-29T15:01:06Z"),
                    "electionTime" : Timestamp(1443540958, 1),
                    "electionDate" : ISODate("2015-09-29T15:35:58Z"),
                    "configVersion" : 1,
                    "self" : true
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "name" : "10.10.40.10:10000",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 2,
                    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                    "uptime" : 2603,
                    "optime" : Timestamp(1443538866, 970),
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-09-29T15:01:06Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-09-29T16:19:20.174Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-09-29T16:19:21.176Z"), 


"pingMs" : 1,
                    "configVersion" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "name" : "10.10.50.10:10000",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 2,
                    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                    "uptime" : 2451,
                    "optime" : Timestamp(1443538866, 970),
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-09-29T15:01:06Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-09-29T16:19:21.826Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-09-29T16:19:20.278Z"),

"pingMs" : 1,
                    "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
                    "configVersion" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 3,
                    "name" : "10.10.60.10:10000",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 2,
                    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                    "uptime" : 18155,
                    "optime" : Timestamp(1443538866, 970),
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-09-29T15:01:06Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-09-29T16:19:20.183Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-09-29T16:19:20.687Z" ),

     "pingMs" : 1,
                    "configVersion" : 1
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1 }
```

The version of MongoDB used is v3.0.6, running in docker container Digital ocean and using weave to enable containers to communicate in different droplets.
Our set up is having 4 droplets

- each running one router (total 4)
- Three config servers
- 4 shard that contains 4 replica members
- In one droplet contains 1 primary and secondary on other droplets

So my question is how to fix this issue or is this normal on MongoDB v3.0.6? 
And is this setup ideal to be in a production environment??

Thanks in advance,
Ronald

Answer (score 0):

The `syncingTo` field is only present on the output of `rs.status()` on secondary and recovering members, and holds the hostname of the member from which this instance is syncing. You can also see it from `logs` for ex- `tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`.

Your sharding cluster is very rich but i suggest that it would enough with two replica of each shard so `Replication Factor RF=3` for a shard. It cuts the cost. And still you can cut by run `mongos` on one of two `secondary` node.

Comment: Thanks Hitesh for the advice, I think I managed to figured out why I am getting "could not find member to sync from". For example I have 3 replica members in a shard and I was viewing replica status on my browser on one of replica members the message "could not find 
member to sync from" appears but when I am not on my browser goes off.
Do you mean by RF=3 is 1 primary and 2 Secondary?